# Why filter not catch 0 and return two numbers, instead three?

Tags: javascript

Why 0 && 0%2 === 0 returns 0 instead true? And the digit 0 does not fall into the array after filter().

```
/*
    0%2 returns 0;
    0 && 0%2 returns 0; 
    0 && 0%2 === 0 returns 0 instead true;
    0 === 0 returns true. I am confused.
*/
const y = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
.map(x => +x)                       // [0,1,2,3,4,5]
.filter(x => x && x % 2 === 0)      // [2,4] ,instead [0,2,4]
.reduce((accum, item)=> accum * item); // 8
console.log(y); //8
```

Comment: @NickA Why you don't write it as the answer of the question ?

Comment: @Christo on phone and wanted to get to PC to find references/a dupe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain a bit, you miss brackets in here:

```
 0 && 0%2 returns 0; 
 0 && 0%2 === 0 returns 0 instead true;
```

With brackets:

```
(0 && 0%2) === 0 returns true;
```

This happens because in your example comparision occurs before logical sum. So basically:

```
0%2 === 0 returns true;
0 && true returns 0;
```

Comment: Thanks I now understand. Code can not be changed. 

0 && 0%2 === 0 returns 0 because:
First 0%2 === 0 returns true;
Second 0 && true returns 0

Comment: @OlegZinchenko `0%2 === 0` never gets run, because of short circuiting

Comment: @NickA Technically yes, any decent language will cut it out, but it illustrates the point well. :)

Answer (score 2):

0 is falsey, so the `x` in `x && ...` is false.